# Morgan does not use colors in console printout

Tags: node.js, morgan

Is there a limitation or rule how you have to setup / define morgan so it still honors the set color schema ? i currently have the following morgan setup.

```
morgan.token('date', (req, res, tz) => {
  return moment().tz(tz).format();
})

morgan.format('myformat', '[:date[America/Los_Angeles]][:remote-addr] ":method :url" :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms')

app.use(morgan('myformat', function (tokens, req, res) {
  return chalk.blue(tokens.method(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.red(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
}))
```

when i use

```
app.use(morgan( function (tokens, req, res) {
  return chalk.blue(tokens.method(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.red(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
}))
```

it uses my set colors but not when i use a custom format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to OzW pointers i was able to make it work with the below code and by passing the format definition i used before. Works like a charm with all the desired colors.

```
app.use(morgan( function (tokens, req, res) {

  return chalk.yellow(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS Z z'))
    + ' ' + chalk.blue(tokens['remote-addr'](req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.cyanBright(tokens.method(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.magentaBright(tokens.status(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.red(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are calling the `morgan` function wrong.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#morganformat-options):

> `morgan(format, options)`
>
> Create a new morgan logger middleware function using the given format
>   and options. The format argument may be a string of a predefined name
>   (see below for the names), a string of a format string, or a function
>   that will produce a log entry.
>
> The format function will be called with three arguments tokens, req,
>   and res...

So when you call:

```
app.use(morgan('myformat', function (tokens, req, res) {
  return chalk.blue(tokens.method(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res))
    + ' ' + chalk.red(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
}))
```

The second argument (the function) is not doing what you want it because morgan thinks it's the `options` argument. The only way I see to achieve what you want is to do declare both the tokens order and their colors inside the function you pass to `morgan` like they show in the [example](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-a-custom-format-function):

```
const loggerMiddleware = morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
    return [
        '[' + tokens['date'](req, res) + ']',
        '[' + tokens["remote-addr"](req, res) + ']',
        '"' + chalk.blue(tokens["method"](req, res)) + chalk.green(tokens["url"](req, res)) + '"',
       // add more tokens here...
    ].join(' ')
});

app.use(loggerMiddleware);
```